# Oracle trigger executing external file before insert operation

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-trigger

I've created Oracle trigger which execute external python file through `DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB()` but it executes python file first then insert row into table.I want exactly opposite operation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sample
AFTER INSERT ON client

BEGIN

  EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB("JOB CONTAN PYTHON FILE");

END;
```

Tell me right way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between the row(s) being inserted into the table and those rows being visible to another session. Until the data is committed then those inserted rows cannot be seen by any other transaction. If your python code tries to connect to the database to look at those rows, it won't see them.

Equally, your transaction can't report back to the client (in your case SQL Developer) that the insert succeeded until the trigger has completed. In this case it needs to wait until the python call has completed before returning.

Generally triggers are considered 'bad practice', though they do have some good applications. Having a session wait on an external task is also something to avoid. I'd recommend you rethink your approach to whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to create application which will produce result after  every insertion.I have  python script ready but which approach would be suitable. Please assist me

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that?

Think!

- you have a table
- there's a trigger on that table
- trigger fires when you insert data into the table and ...
- ... calls the Python script

So, how can that script run *before* inserting a row, if exactly that action - a row being inserted - triggers & runs the Python script?

Unless you prove me wrong, everything should be OK.

Comment: I'm using Oracle sqldeveloper and inserting values directly into table through GUI.but when  I click on commit button it starts trigger executes python script and if that script get executed it shows insert operation committed.    If python script continue to run ,Oracle won't insert and reflect result in table